# Radio button staying checked even after I check a different one?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I have radio buttons in a piece of HTML like

```
<form id="speed-form">
  <table class="table-condensed table-responsive">
      <tr>
          <td><input type="radio" name="speed" value="slow"></td>
          <td align="left">Slow</td>
       </tr>
      <tr>
          <td><input type="radio" name="speed" value="medium" checked="checked"></td>
          <td align="left">Medium</td>
      </tr>   
      <tr>
         <td><input type="radio" name="speed" value="fast" /></td>
         <td align="left">Fast</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

and the `value` of the currently checked `input` is meant to control my Javascript game. I get that `value` with

```
SG.startNew($('#speed-form input[type="radio"]:checked').val());
```

The problem is that while I have the medium one selected on page load, it doesn't seem to unselect when I click either of the other 2.

**Proof:** Click [here](http://playclassicsnake.com/play)

Comment: it is working for me.... how to recreate the case

Comment: Try hard refresh, also try on different browsers. Its working.

Comment: working for me aswell,

Answer (score 0):

You have some sort of modal or popover blocking the input buttons.

[image]

After selecting and deleting it, I was able to select the radio buttons.

[image]